# IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I sorted several .csv files with glob, then I concatenated them and now I am trying to filter for a specific column("Contracts") in a Pandas Dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

gas_prices_2019= sorted(glob('Gas prices/2019****_PowernextGasFutures_SettlementPrices.csv'))
gas_prices_2019

df_2019= pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file).assign(filename = file)
           for file in gas_prices_2019), ignore_index = True)    

df_2019.loc[df['Contracts'] == 'CEGH VTP 2020' ]
```

However I am getting the following error message at the last row of the code:

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

I researched and found that this error message comes up when the .loc command is missing, but it is there in my code.
I would like to filter to the rows, where in the column "Contracts" the value is "CEGH VTP 2020"

Can anyone please help?

Thank you. Best Regards

Comment: You have a typo in your filter: you are using df['Contracts'] instead of df_2019['Contracts']. Maybe this is causing the error.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it solved the problem!